# Android - inapp-billing-v3 library consume product not working

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to develop some in app purchase in my app using the library [inapp-billing-v3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3). I have two type:

remove ads = not consumable

receive coins = consumable

With the code I have I can purchase the "not consumable" product without problems however, the "consumable item is not working at all. when clicked nothing happens, the in app window is not opening. I just get:

> D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
>
> D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Why is this happening? How can I implement consumable purchase properly using this library?

My app is in beta test

```
//TODO Ads Click
        btn_ads.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Start new list activity
            public void onClick(View v) {             

                UtilityClass.delayFast(700, new UtilityClass.DelayCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void afterDelay() {

                        bp.purchase(ShopActivity.this, getString(R.string.remove_adverts)); //working
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //TODO shop1 Click
        btn_shop1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Start new list activity
            public void onClick(View v) {

                UtilityClass.delayFast(700, new UtilityClass.DelayCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void afterDelay() {
                        bp.consumePurchase(getString(R.string.coins_300));// not working
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you share your xml file? Can you try to put messagebox to see afterDelay() method is called correctly? if method is getting called correctly, check syntax of consume purchase you need to send token int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), token);

Answer (score 0):

In `AppBillingService` class consume purchase Have three parameter like :

```
consumePurchase(int apiVersion, java.lang.String packageName, java.lang.String purchaseToken)
```

and you provide only one parameter so can you show what you done inside `consumePurchase` method

Answer (score 0):

You have to purchase and then consume.

```
       bp.purchase(ShopActivity.this, getString(R.string.coins_300));
       bp.consumePurchase(getString(R.string.coins_300));
```